# Data not Inserting into Database and no error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem...

Im trying to take data inserted into my html5 form and insert it into a database. Now i have the form made along with a script that should be working; instead there is no data being inserted into the database and there is no error showing. Please help.

form.php

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="process.php">
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
<input type="submit" id="Login" class="form-control" value="Log In">
</form>
```

process.php

```
<?
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "toor") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("formd") or die(mysql_error());  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database.";
?>
```

Now i know this isnt a secure way to store passwords or usernames but this isnt for any website really i just wanna know how to take information from my form and store it into a database.

Comment: try changing your line to this: 

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('$username', '$password')") or die(mysql_error());

You're catching errors for selecting and connecting the database but not the insert.

Comment: You haven't passed column names in your insert query, so make sure you have only two columns in `data` table.

Comment: I have replaced that line chris and its still not working. also kamal in the column there is username and password.

Answer (score 2):

You've added minimal error handling to all mysql functions call but the one involved in the actual query....

The script is also [prone to sql injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

The mysql_* extension is mared as deprecated, better [pick another mysql extension](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

```
<?php
$mysql = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "toor")
  or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("formd", $mysql)
  or die(mysql_error($mysql)); 

$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'], $mysql);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'], $mysql);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('$username', '$password')", $mysql)
  or die(mysql_error($mysql));
echo "Your information has been successfully added to the database.";
```

using `or die(mysql_error())` can lead to [Information Leakage issues](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-Information_Leakage_and_Improper_Error_Handling)

Comment: Thank you this worked! Well displayed an error but i can fix it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Im still learning the very basics myself, i have not tested this and just snipped it out of a very long sql script i have so it may work and may not, hopefully it does help you out.. if not take a look at the link below the code. Hope it works for you or may need a little tweak.  Thanks

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$submit         = $_POST['submit'];
$username     = $_POST['username'];
$password     = $_POST['password'];

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'toor';
$conn   = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO data (username','password')
              VALUES('$username','$password')";

mysql_select_db('formd');
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if (!$retval) {
    die('Could not enter your data: '.mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered your dara successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
} else {
    echo "Something has gone wrong.";
}

?>
```

Alternative link to take a look at:    http://www.jotform.com/help/126-How-to-send-Submissions-to-Your-MySQL-Database-Using-PHP